# Is it better to define condition variables or to use no variables and check the condition each time?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

Is it better to check a condition once, define variables, then use those variables?

```
<c:if test="${someCondition}">
    <c:set var="varOne" value="1" />
    <c:set var="varTwo" value="2" />
    <c:set var="varThree" value="3" />
    <c:set var="varFour" value="4" />
    <c:set var="varFive" value="5" />
</c:if>

${varOne}
...
${varTwo}
...
${varThree}
...
${varFour}
...
${varFive}
```

Or is it better to use no variables and check the condition each time a value needs to be output?

```
${someCondition ? "1" : ''}
...
${someCondition ? "2" : ''}
...
${someCondition ? "3": ''}
...
${someCondition ? "4": ''}
...
${someCondition ? "5": ''}
```

Comment: 'Define conditional variables' != 'conditionally define variables'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you going to show every variable in many places in you page, first approach (when check a condition just once) will be more preferable. Because it allows you to avoid duplication of code.

If you will show variables just once, you don't need additional `<c:if` and second approach is ok. Because it more simple and more readable.

---

Of course, this is just my opinion, but I would prefer move this logic to controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController{

    @RequestMapping("/my-mapping")
    public String showView(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("varOne", someCondition?1:null);
        model.addAttribute("varTwo", someCondition?2:null);
        //etc ...
        return "view-name";
    }
}
```

In this case your view will stay clear and simple, and all business logic will be in one place (by the way, JSP will show nothing, when you are passing `null` as value).

Comment: Thanks, Ken. The first approach does seem more maintainable to me because all the logic is in one place at the top and it does make more sense when the variables will be used multiple times. In my case I will only use the variables once. I was just was not sure about the performance considerations of multiple condition checks vs defined variables. Knowing this now, do you still suggest the second option in my case since I only need to use the variables once (assuming I don't have access to the controller)?

Comment: @Talha Simple comparison operation is almost nothing for modern computers. To feel some difference in performance, you need to compare millions of values. Don't worry about it. In same time readability and development productivity is very important point. When you or somebody else will look for code of page after long time, it is easy to forget, that variable `${varOne}` defined somewhere else (especially when code of page big enough). It looks like it came from model. Not clear moment. So, my answer is yes. I still suggest you second approach in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Ken.